# iOS location updates app in background

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location, background-process

I'm wondering if the functionality I want to do add to my app will likely/unlikely be rejected by Apple's review team.

I want to turn on significant change location services when the app is in the background, and then fire off a web request when a new location is found for the user.

I'm interested in doing this to set up push notifications. The push notification I want to send to the user needs the user's location for it to be useful.

Apple writes, "An app should request background location services only if the absence of those services would impair its ability to operate." in the following link.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html

Is what I'm trying to do a good idea?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to mention in your application description on iTunes App Store, that your application uses location services in background, which may drain your device battery.

Comment: significant location change service does not appreciably drain the battery since it is based on cell tower and wifi and does not use GPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For location update in background, there is no need of push notification.

As you have done is fine. Just add one key in plist file that inform the app that, app will work in background and will take user's GPS location.

Now, you have to inform the user that, your app will track the user's GPS location, and because of continuous location tracking, it will affect on devices battery.

You can do this by adding the line in info page of the app. And you can also mentioned in application description which is displaying on app store.

Then apple will not reject your app due to GPS tracking.

Hope it will help to approve your app.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Its a perfectly good idea as long as your app would be impaired if you did not have that functionality. If you submit it on those guidelines, there is no reason Apple would decline your app. I would make sure to tell the user somewhere in the app that your app will be tracking their position in the background